# Who were the people Kominsky was thinking about?

Tags: character, the-kominsky-method

In the second season of *The Kominsky method*, the main character hears pretty bad news from the doctor - it seems that Sandy is facing a "debilitating treatment".
The doctors then ask Kominsky, "does he have anyone that he can go through with this treatment with him?". What follows up is a series of pictures that comes to Sandy's mind.

The first few are obvious: his daughter, his best friend and his girlfriend, but the rest are a bit more confusing:

[image]

Then we have a pornographic picture:

[image]

[image]

This obviously is Mother Theresa

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So who are those people/characters? Why Kominsky keeps thinking that they could help him? I understand that the porn actress is an obvious joke that even while he is (nearly) dying, he can think about sex and Mother Theresa suggests (for a brief second) that he might try praying, but the rest? I understand that this is the "[Rule of funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)"<sup>TV tropes warning!</sup>  But are those people in any way meaningful to this situation?

Comment: They are Richard Chamberlain as *Dr Kildare* plus Moe, Curly & Larry - *The Three Stooges*

Answer (score 1):

1. Kathleen Turner/ Cybil Shepard (?)
2. Pornstar
3. A doctor (Richard Chamberlain)
4. Mother Theresa

The Three stooges

1. Moe Howard
2. Larry Fine
3. Curly Howard

---

- In the 1980's they portrayed a strong women who were kind of cynical and down to earth. A person who would stick to their guns and make sure Sany don't quit treatment.
- a pornstar, to ease the harshneas of treatmen and give some type of "vent".
- Doctor, who's better to help you with sickness if not a doctor. It's also Richard Chamberlain.
- Mother Theresa, a person that is known for taking care of people who are sick and dying.
- Member of farce/slapstic comedy group. Their antics were based on not very bright people doing things.

The underlying idea *might be* like that: A person who you can feel attraction to but cold and proffesional. A person who you can feel only sexual attraction. A person who might be proffesional, you don't feel attracted to but migh be attracted to you (Chamberlain was playing males that young women falled in love with while, in private life, being gay). A proffesional who even with their appearance make you not think about sex. A person who... NOW YOU'RE JUST BEING SILLY, three stooges? You want to kill him?